# CEF3 crash when loading large images

Tags: delphi, chromium, tchromium

I'm use CEF 3.2454.1344.g2782fb8 (Chromium 45.0.2454.101) in my project in Delphi 10.1. (I have to use a fairly old version of CEF/Chromium for backwards compatibility with WinXP). So I noticed a strange pattern: the application crashes every time when I try to open a web page contains a large image (jpeg >2Mb, for example). I will be grateful for any ideas that will help me avoid such crashes.

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/issues/23#issuecomment-294303310)

Comment: Victoria, that's awesome! Seems it works for me!